How to pass value from component to aura js controller from button click
I have this below code.
   <aura:iteration items="{!v.filteredTemplates}"  var="template"> 
                                    <tr class="slds-hint-parent"> 
                                        <td data-label="Template Name"> 
                                            <div class="slds-truncate" title="{!template.Name}">{!template.Name}</div> 
                                        </td> 
                                        <td data-label="Action" > 
                                            <lightning:button aura-id="templ" value="{!template.Id}" label="Select" onclick="{!c.selectTemplate}"  /> 
                                        </td> 
                                    </tr> 
</aura:iteration> 

when click button I want to pass {!template.Id} to js controller.
I tried this but not working.
var selectedTemplateId = component.find('templ').get('v.value');

can help me to do this?

You need to ensure that the value is correctly passed to the controller function. The issue with your current approach is that component.find('templ') returns an array of components because you have multiple buttons with the same aura:id within the iteration.
You can pass the template.Id to the JavaScript controller when clicking the button, you can use the data-* attribute or directly access the button's value attribute.
<aura:iteration items="{!v.filteredTemplates}" var="template"> 
        <tr class="slds-hint-parent"> 
                <td data-label="Template Name"> 
                        <div class="slds-truncate" title="{!template.Name}">{!template.Name}</div> 
                </td> 
                <td data-label="Action"> 
                        <lightning:button label="Select" onclick="{!c.selectTemplate}" value="{!template.Id}" /> 
                </td> 
        </tr> 
</aura:iteration>

Then, retrieve the template.Id from the event's target element.
({
        selectTemplate: function(component, event, helper) {
                var selectedTemplateId = event.getSource().get("v.value");
                console.log("Selected Template Id: " + selectedTemplateId);

        }
})

The event.getSource().get("v.value") retrieves the value of the value attribute of the button, which contains the template.Id.

Thank yo so much its working. if i need to pass another variable can I put like  <lightning:button value="{!template.Id}" name="{!template.Name}"  label="Select" onclick="{!c.selectTemplate}"  />

Yes, You can pass like this: <lightning:button value="{!template.Id}" name="{!template.Name}" label="Select" onclick="{!c.selectTemplate}" /> and get like this: var selectedTemplateName = event.getSource().get("v.name");

Thank you. working
